# Pull Request Declined Now cannot see the earlier files with changes in git status

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

I raised a PULL REQUEST on Bitbucket and I committed and pushed my changes to branch by following the below method:

```
git status
git add ‘<file name>'
git stash
git fetch
git pull origin master
git stash list
git stash pop
git add ‘<file name>'
git status
git commit -m "message"
git push origin "<branch name>"
```

Then created Pull request for review.

However, I have pushed some wrong files. So I declined my Pull Request and now want to raise the new pull request.

When I go to terminal and type git status. It shows only one file. However I want to again commit and push all the files excluding the ones which were wrong.

Please help me as I am new to git process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git status` is purely local - it does not communicate with any other instances of your repo. As a result, it has no idea what you have or have not done on Bitbucket (or GitHub, or GitLab, etc.).

Your simplest solution will probably be to abandon the "bad" branch and start fresh with a new one. You'll still have to delete the bad branch from Bitbucket (do that in Bitbucket itself) but otherwise you'll have a clean slate.

If you'd prefer to keep the existing branch for some reason, then you can either revert the bad commit (`git reflog`, get the hash for one or more bad commits, `git revert $HASH`, continue as usual) or reset the branch to a "good" state (`git reflog`, get the hash for the commit you want to roll back to, `git reset --hard $HASH`, make new commits, then `git push -f`). Revert will record a new commit that undoes the bad ones; reset will roll the branch back such that the bad ones no longer exist, but reset will also undo any uncommitted changes. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert has some further details on revert, as well as a general guide to when it might be better to use some other method.

Comment: Thank you so much Jim! I created a new branch that solved it. Just one more question please. Now I am in new branch and committed the changes and pushed it. However, I need to make some more edits. After that can I add these new changes to same branch ? or again need to create a new one.Please tell me step by step procedure in git.

Comment: Yes, you can keep adding commits to a branch. There's a bit of risk over time that each branch will drift from the others, but you can rebase or merge to solve that.

Comment: Okay Jim. Thank you for your help and useful information.

Answer (score 0):

So I got my issue resolved by creating a new branch. And when I committed more changes I just declined the old Pull Request and raised a new one as changes committed again goes to same branch.So my issue is resolved.Thanks!